# How to detect whether a seekbar progress change is decreasing or increasing?

Tags: android, seekbar

The progress change event can be notified by `onProgressChanged` in interface `OnSeekBarChangeListener()`.

But how to know whether a change decrease the progress or increase it? Or is there an interface or method like:
`onSeekBarProgressDecreased(....)`  or `onSeekBarProgressIncreased(...)`

Comment: Keep track of the previous value?

Comment: You can track the present value and compare it with previous value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no interface available for progress decrease or increase events. You have to keep track of it. You can use something like this.

```
int prevProgress;
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
     @Override
      public oid onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
       int diff = progress - prevProgress;
       if(diff > 0){
          //increase
          }
       else{
          //decrease
          }
        prevProgress = progress;
      }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private prevValue;

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {



              @Override

              public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
if(progressValue < prevValue){

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Progress decreased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }else if(progressValue > prevValue){


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Progress increased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

prevValue = progresValue;

}
    ....


                }
```